# Как получить id кнопки на которую нажимаем?

Tags: php, jquery

Использую bootstrap datatable, данные в нее загружаю динамически, они приходят в json.
У каждой записи есть есть кнопка с атрибутом data-id=**10** где 10 - id это записи.

Мне нужно при клике на эту кнопку определить какой ее `data-id`

На станице есть код для этого, но он не работает если данные подгружаются динамически:

```
$('[data-id]').click( function() {
    $('#id').val($(this).data('id'));
});
```

А если просто на этой же странице добавить кнопочку - то все работает, пример:

```js
$('[data-id]').click( function() {
  $('#id').val($(this).data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="1">Кнопка id 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="2">Кнопка id 2</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" id="id">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Каким образом получит ID записи которые подгружаются динамически?

P.s. в гугл хром в консоле разработчика атрибут `data-id` отображает id записи. а при клике почему-то нет.

Comment: @user202854 и как мне это применить? не совсем понял вас...

Comment: извиняюсь, не совсем в тему. а нельзя ли родительским блокам из подгружаемого контента давать класс с id ?

Comment: Если у вас сначала устанавливается обработчик события `click` для элементов `[data-id]`, а потом только создаются эти элементы, то это работать и не должно. Устанавливайте обработчик после создания элементов или же грубо прописывайте им атрибут `onclick`

Comment: Вам надо после загрузки json в dom заново проинициализировать событие  `click`

Comment: @Pyramidhead можно пожалуйста пример?

Answer (score 4):

У вас не работают обработчики клика для динамически созданных строк. Обработчики событий применяются только к тем элементам, которые существовали в момент их применения. То есть если у вас выполняется такой код

```
$('[data-id]').click(function() {...});
```

он создаст обработчики только для элементов с атрибутом `data-id` существующих в данный момент. Для подобных элементов, которые появятся на странице позже данных обработчиков просто не будет. Есть два пути решения данной проблемы:

1. **Наивный**. Назначайте обработчики в момент создания новых элементов. Например после загрузки данных вы можете каждый раз вызывать такой код `$('[data-id]').click(function() {...});`. Это вариант совсем плох, поскольку добавит дублирующиеся обработчики для элементов, которые уже существовали. Это можно обойти простым ходом - например добавлять класс для уже обработанных строк и фильтровать по его отсутствию `$('[data-id]:not(.js-click-present)').click(function() {...}).addClass('.js-click-present');`
2. **Оптимальный**. Установите обработчик через `container.on('click', '[data-id]', function(e) {...})` где container - это родительский (хоть document) элемент, который существует на странице в момент назначения обработчика клика. Желательно чтобы этот контейнер был как можно меньшим (будет меньше ложных срабатываний обработчика) - то есть как можно ближе по иерархии к добавляемым элементам. В этом варианте у вас на странице будет меньше обработчиков событий и в целом производительность будет выше.